# How to pass a array of string from fortran to c?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to pass a array of string which I filled in fortran code to C. However, every times I tried to check the result I found that each one of the character string is printed as a whole array in C. Can anyone help through this? 
This is fortran part of code:

```
        SUBROUTINE hello (Characters)
CHARACTER*(16)  Characters(5)
Characters=(/"ABCD","BCDF","CVFG","D HG","J67F"/)
return
END
```

and this is C code:

```
    void hello_(char *[16]);
    int main(int argc,char **args)
    {
    char        Character2[5][16];
    int         j;
    hello_(&Character2);
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
    printf("String [ %d ] = %s \n",j,Character2[j]);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

The results I get is this:

```
 String [ 0 ] = ABCD            BCDF            CVFG            D HG                  J67F            `����U 
 String [ 1 ] = BCDF            CVFG            D HG            J67F            `����U 
 String [ 2 ] = CVFG            D HG            J67F            `����U 
 String [ 3 ] = D HG            J67F            `����U 
 String [ 4 ] = J67F            `����U
```

I want to know why I can't access to each one of those strings which I passed from fortran to C? I mean, how can I make sure that ,like, Character2[1] is exactly what I made in fortran, "ABCD"!
Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Could you please edit them into your post.

Comment: Does fortran NUL terminate strings?

Comment: what does hello2 do? SHow its code

Comment: @pm100 Sorry! all of them is only one function hello, both C an fortran! That was a mistake!

Comment: @jxh No, the fortran strings are not null-terminated

Answer (score 0):

Since the FORTRAN strings are not NUL terminated, the C code will not be able to detect the end of the string being printed.

Since your strings are meant to be no longer than a certain length, you can specify that in your print statement (although, it is unclear to me that FORTRAN will fill with spaces if you don't provide a long enough string):

```
printf("String [ %d ] = %.4s \n",j,Character2[j]);
```

If your FORTRAN code knows it will be called from C, then it should add the NUL byte to the strings before returning the array back to the caller.

Comment: Thanks! Do you how I can add the NULL byte to the string of arrays in the fortran , like here? Should I use CHAR(0) or '\0'!

Comment: Does your FORTRAN have `C_NULL_CHAR` defined?